# Aws toolkit for intellij unable to load S3: NoSuchBucketException: The specified bucket does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, aws-toolkit

I have been using AWS toolkit for intellij for a while now, it was working fine, I was able to create and update lambdas until now. No changes were done on IAM Roles or access keys, in fact it's able to display the lambda functions in AWS Explorer, but It's unable to load S3 buckets. Without loading S3 buckets I won't be able to publish or update lambdas.

[image: The screen shot of error]

[image: the screen shot of AWS Explorer]

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and re-installing the plug-in from the latest?

Comment: Yes I have. It was unfruitful too.

Comment: What's the exact version of plugin are you using?

Comment: it's version 1.9-193